# Is it better to donate during Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, sadaqah

I'd like to donate a substantial amount of money to charity, but it's not anything urgent. My friends recommend that I do it during Ramadan because the donations would be worth more in Ramadan.

Is this a valid point of view? Should I hold off on donating? Slightly off topic, are there logistical reasons why I shouldn't donate during Ramadan (like if anyone has experience dealing with too many donations then)?

Comment: are you sure? you know that you will be alive till Ramadan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course donating during Ramadan is best time. But the point is that we don't have to Wait till Ramadan. As We never know that when our time will come (death). 
Also, there is a hadith that talks about doing good deed hurriedly, or not to wait in doing good deed.

> "So hasten towards all that is good". (2:148)
>
> "And march forth in the way (which leads to) forgiveness from your
>   Rubb, and for Jannah as wide as are the heavens and the earth,
>   prepared for Al-Muttaqun (the pious)". (3:133)
>
> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of
>   Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) said, "Be prompt in doing good
>   deeds (before you are overtaken) by turbulence which would be like a
>   part of the dark night. A man would be a believer in the morning and
>   turn to disbelief in the evening, or he would be a believer in the
>   evening and turn disbeliever in the morning, and would sell his Faith
>   for worldly goods.'' [Muslim].

Also

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of
>   Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) said, "Hasten to do good deeds
>   before you are overtaken by one of the seven afflictions.'' Then
>   (giving a warning) he said, "Are you waiting for such poverty which
>   will make you unmindful of devotion; or prosperity which will make you
>   corrupt, or disease as will disable you, or such senility as will make
>   you mentally unstable, or sudden death, or Ad-Dajjal who is the worst
>   expected absent, or the Hour, and the Hour will be most grievous and
>   most bitter". [At-Tirmidhi].

You never know that if your act of charity can give you much more reward, than donating in Ramadan..

So it’s better to donate as soon as possible. And when you get the time in Ramadan, then donate in that time as well.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not clear when we will die, but my response was from the superiority of Ramadan in compare with other months(in donation). Good luck.  HELE BIK!

Answer (score 2):

```
           In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

I, as a (Shia) Muslim believe that Ramadan is the finest month of the year. 
Of course donating is always good. But I think it could be so better on Ramadan, how come?

**Since according to the third verse of Sura Qadr, The Night of Qadr is better than a thousand months {1}, thus perhaps the reward of our acts will be more than one thousand times, won't be?!**
or perhaps very more than one thousand times, since it says the night of Qadr is better than one thousand months, not better than one thousand days.

Hence I recommend you buddy to donate on the mentioned night.

Of course the opinion of @Farhan is true that we ought not to waste time..., since it is not clear that when we will die, but my response is from the aspect of Ramadan superiority in compare with other months.

On the other hand, I think the intention is so important, how come? 
I mean: for instance it is your intention to donate some specified amount of money on Ramadan, then suddenly you die, so definitely Allah will give its reward to you, won't he?

---

**{1}: لَیْلَةُ الْقَدْرِ خَیْرٌ مِنْ أَ لْفِ شَهْرٍ**

Comment: Both this and Farhan's answer are correct, but I'll go with that answer because of the "hasten towards doing good" verse. Thank you.